# SharePoint Online - Social Media Integration

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I have a requirement to allow employees to share "News Posts pages" to their social media accounts (Facebook, LinkedIn, and Instagram) from our intranet SharePoint Online Site. In addition, it is important to validate employees' posts before they actually publically publish the post to make sure they are in line with our social media guidelines.

Could you please suggest if the above requirements are feasible on SharePoint Online? If so, could you please provide a sample from the community if someone did something similar because I believe this should be done with a custom web part (SP-Dev-FX).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online sites are not publicly accessible, e.g. users need to login to access SharePoint sites. Therefore sharing pages via Facebook or LinkedIn, doesn't appear to be a plausible use case because those clicking on the link from Facebook will need to login to view the SharePoint news post.